# Is this generalization of Hilbert's basis theorem already known (and is it even true)?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Hilbert's basis theorem states that if $R$ is a commutative noetherian ring (i.e. every ideal $I\subseteq R$ is finitely generated) then $R[x]$ is noetherian as well.

I immediately thought that this could be proven using the fact that $R[x]/(x)\cong R$, where $(x)$ is the ideal generated by the polynomial $x$.
Indeed I am pretty sure that I came up with a proof for it. The main part is just showing that for any (commutative) ring $S$ and ideals $I\subseteq S$ and  $J\subseteq S$, the quotient ideal $I/J\subseteq S/J$ is not finitely generated when $I$ is not finitely generated and $J$ is finitely generated (where $I/J$ is the image of $I$ under the quotient map $q:S\rightarrow S/J$).

Then it follows easily that a ring $R$ is noetherian if there is a finitely generated ideal $J\subseteq R$ s.t. $R/J$ is noetherian. (If $R$ had a non-finitely generated ideal $I\subseteq R$ then $I/J$ would also not be finitely generated which is a contradiction).

This generalizes Hilbert's basis theorem, since $R[x]/(x)\cong R$ and $(x)$ is obviously finitely generated.

My question is if this generalization can even be true or if I have made a bad mistake and if it is true wether this is already known. I can not imagine that it is both true and not known, since the proof was pretty easy, but I couldn't find anything on the internet and you never know.

Answer (score 2):

Let $R \subset \mathbb{Q}[x]$ be the subring made with the $P \in \mathbb{Q}[x]$ such that $P(0) \in \mathbb{Z}$.

It’s easy to see that $2R=\{P \in \mathbb{Q}[x],\, P(0) \in 2\mathbb{Z}\}$. So $R/2R \cong \mathbb{F}_2$ is a Noetherian ring, but (for instance) the sequence of ideals (of $R$) $(2^{-n}x)$ is increasing and not stationary.

Comment: Is 2R finitely generated in R? It seems it should be, but I can not find a set of generators. That might just be on me though. If it is not finitely generated then it is not a counter example

Comment: $2R$ is generated by $2$.

Comment: I'd write $R=\mathbb Z+x\mathbb Q[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

the problem with your proof is, that I/J only makes sense if J is a subset of  I.

So you can only prove that every ideal in R[x] which is contained in (x) is finitely generated.

Comment: I used a slightly different defintion of I/J. If p is the canonical quotient map from S to S/J then I/J is just the image of I under p. I'm sorry I didn't make this clear, I thought this would be the standard definition. I proved that this is actually an ideal as well (or atleast I think I did).

Comment: Sure, but then you’re just showing that $I+J$ is finitely generated. But this doesn’t *a priori* imply that $I$ is finitely generated.